# how to move object to specific coordinates on the screen with js

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

Is there a way to move an object, such as an image, to specific coordinates on the screen, using  JS or jQuery?
I mean not to use percentage or pixels for its position and the distance from top/left.

More specifically, I want by clicking an image to trigger the following event: Some images, that begin from the center of the screen, to animate and move to specific position on the screen, in a way that this position does not change when the width and height of the window changes.

Is there a way, for example, to divide the screen into 100 pieces and make the image be always on the 40th of them?

Or will I have to use SVG animation for that?

Actually I want to make the background image, with the image that animates, fully responsive ..

Below is my code:
html -->

```
<div class="fullmenu">
   <img id="stable" src="menu/stable.svg">
   <img id="fr7" src="menu/fr7.svg">
</div>
```

CSS -->

```
#fullmenu{
    position: relative;
}
#stable{
    position: absolute;
}
#fr7{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

jQuery -->

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stable").one("click", function(){
        $("#fr7").animate({
          top:"+=220",
          left:"+=420"
        },2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok to clarify: You want to move the images to 40% of the screen width (say 200px). But when the screen size goes up or down, they should remain at the OLD 40% of screen width (200px) not the new one?

Comment: What do you mean by "image be always on the 40th of them"?

Comment: I hope I will respond to both of you. 
Let's say that we have a new coordination system on our screen, that the x-axis starts from 0 and ends at 100. I want my image's x-coordinate to be 40 always..Is that more clear?

Comment: If I increased the screen size, would the new screen size still go from 0-100 or would the new one go from 0-120 (or 130, 140, 123123 etc.)

Comment: I want the new screen size to go from 0-100 again :)

Comment: Ok in that case you would use %. E.g. left: 40%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stable").one("click", function(){
        $("#fr7").animate({
          top: "40vh",
          left: "40vw"
        },2000);
    });
});
```

Using Viewport Sized Typography you can achieve what you are describing.

You could also use % such as `top: '40%', left: '40%'`  however the % are based upon the element's first relative parent's size. So unless #fullmenu is 100% of the screen size (both height and width) it won't work.

Comment: Viewport Sized Typography worked, thank you very much, it solved my problem!
as for %, even if the width and height are 100% it does not work..Should their position be something specific?

Comment: Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqZwPx the html, body must also have height: 100% set.

Comment: Thank you! I used vh and vw for my problem before, but I just noticed that there is a different behavior in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome ! Why could this happen ??